# What is this 2 pack patience game?

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards, solitaire

[image]
Can anyone tell me what the name of this 2 pack solitaire game is called? I have played it since I was a child but would like to discover the full rules. It is much like standard one pack solitaire except the middle column can only be moved directly onto the ace piles. Other cards can just be moved into black and red sequences

Comment: This appears to be a variant of [Russian Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Bank) (which is known to sport quite a few variants, some of which seemingly more common in some countries than others). I don't know which particular variant this is, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The game I play is for one person only.